# Create a list field linking to PDFs

Tags: entities, files

I'm relatively new to Drupal 7 and I'm a little lost on this one.

I have an "event" Content Type that contains a list field type that displays about five "location" options. Here they are, in key|label form:

Main Entrance|Main Entrance

School Entrance|School Entrance

Park Entrance|Park Entrance

Staff Entrance|Staff Entrance

What I'd like to do is directly link each label to a PDF file containing a map of the entrance location; e.g., `Staff Entrance|<a href="filepath">Staff Entrance</a>`.

When I try to customize the field settings, Drupal tells me that the following tags are allowed in labels: `<a> <b> <big> <code> <del> <em> <i> <ins> <pre> <q> <small> <span> <strong> <sub> <sup> <tt> <ol> <ul> <li> <p> <br> <img>`. But in spite of my efforts to add tags to labels, Drupal changes them to HTML entities and ignores them; e.g., `&lt;Staff Entrance&gt;`. This is the case for all HTML tags.

Is there a reason HTML is not rendering in my labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that a label can't be an anchor (because of XSS).
You may want to use theme_preprocess_field or theme_preprocess_node to wrap the label with an anchor.